# Mule4 deployment configuration

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-cluster

I am new to Mule4.x features. Get to realize that mule-app and mule-deploy has been deprecated. Where and how to provide information about deployment configurations? I can see mule-artifact.json is there but no where I am able to find how to use it with example. Mule docs only talks about elements and it's description but don't have any examples.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A very short description of **mule-artifact.json** is available [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule4-user-guide/v/4.1/intro-packaging#mule-artifact-json).

**mule-deploy.properties** of Mule 3 has auto generated list of config resources, same thing is now available in **mule-artifact.json** as **"configs"** for Mule 4. This section will be automatically updated when new mule xml file is added under src/main/mule. Similarly **redeploymentEnabled** flag is also available in this file.

On the other hand, key-value pairs from **mule-app.properties** must be specified in **Run Configurations** section in AnypointStudio and in **Properties** section on CloudHub.

**AnypointStudio Run Configurations:**
[image: AnypointStudio Run Configurations]

**CloudHub Properties:**
[image: CloudHub Properties]

Comment: Many thanks Sagar for providing pointers in detail.It's really helpful.

Comment: To add to the Sagar answer, you don't need to actually modify the mule-artifact.json except you have very specific requirements. Just be sure to use the latest available version of the Mule Maven Plugin.

Comment: Another point you might like to know is, adding properties here as "secureProperties" will help you to hide the properties in the CloudHub.